# r Mixed model formula - help! (edited)

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, predictive-models, repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis

I am struggling with defining my mixed model formula and would love some help. This is a gene expression data where I want to see if each gene can predict Response — and I am comparing mixed model and linear model, to see if removing the effect of the Cluster variable changes the outcome.

My dependent variable is Response — it is a continuous variable.
My predictors are:

- Gene expression (continuous)
- Participant.ID (character) — 52 individuals
- Time point (continuous) — Although this is a continuous variable, the values are either -7,0,1,7 or 70. I have between 3-5 time points per subject. The reason I chose to make this continuous and not a factor is because it describes time.
- Cluster variable (factor) — a variable that describes a certain characteristic of an individual. It can be one of 3 options.

I used a formula in lme4: `Response ~ gene + TimePoint + Subject + (1|Random)`

but I feel like this may be wrong seeing as each subject has several time points, so maybe I should nest “study time point” under “subject” (?)
Would love some input

**Edit:** after some reading maybe I need to remove study time point because it doesn't have any meaning across individuals? I tried the following formula:

`Response ~ gene  + (1|Cluster) + (1|Cluster:Participant.ID)`
but got the following error:
`Error in eval_f(x, ...) : Downdated VtV is not positive definite`

Also tried this formula:

`Response ~ gene  + (1|Cluster:Participant.ID)` and this: `Response ~ gene  + (1|Cluster) + (1|Participant.ID)`
but got this error: `Warning message: In optwrap(optimizer, devfun, getStart(start, rho$pp), lower = rho$lower,  : convergence code -4 from nloptwrap`

Comment: What is your definition of "nested" in this particular case? It looks to me like time is a continuous variable with a varying number of observations (3 to 5), not values that are dependent upon the subject factor.

Comment: Please edit your question to say more about the nature of the `Subject` and `Random` predictors in your model. With only 3 levels, what you call `Random` wouldn't usually be coded as a "random effect" as your model does. On the other hand, if there are more than a handful of subjects then `Subject` might well be coded as a "random effect." Please add that information to question itself by editing it, as comments are too easily overlooked and can even be lost sometimes.

Comment: edited, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the updated descriptionn :

- you have repeated measures within `Subject` and you have 52 subjects. It does not make sense to fit this as a fixed effect. It should be a grouping variable in the random structure.
- `Random` is "a variable that describes a certain characteristic of an individual. It can be one of 3 options". As such it does not make sense to have this as a grouping variable in the random structure. It should be a fixed effect.
- I can't see any reason why `TimePoint` would be nested within `Subject`

So an appropriate model would be:

```
Response ~ gene + TimePoint + Random + (1 | Subject)
```

---

Edit, now that the OP has been changed so that `Random` has been renamed to `Cluster` and `Subject` has been renamed to `Participant.ID`

The appropriate model would be:

```
Response ~ gene + TimePoint + Cluster + (1 | Participant.ID)
```

Comment: Hi Robert! Thanks for answering. Could you maybe look at the updated post? I think it's much clearer now

Comment: You have changed the name of the variable `Random` to `Cluster` , and `Subject` to `Cluster:Participant.ID` making my answer look nonsensical :(  :(  :(     Anyway, it doesn't really change my answer. In your updated model you seem to have participant nested within cluster, which does not seem to be the case and with only 3 clusters, `(1|Cluster)` does not make sense.

Comment: Sorry about that  thanks! Will try again.

Comment: Please don't change anything else. I have edited my answer with your renamed variables.

Comment: Hi Robert, I tried your model, but I  got this error message `Error in eval_f(x, ...) : Downdated VtV is not positive definite`. I found this is probably a scaling issue since `Response`  is in a different scale than `gene` - so I log10 transformed and now it works (I'm not entirely sure this is correct though).
Another thing I wanted to mention is that the time points are not the same for all individuals. Meaning sample collection was made in the mentioned intervals but they were not the same days in the year between individuals. I'm mentioning this because of the time nesting thing...

Comment: Unless you have good reason to use a *log* transformation, I would start by simply rescaling perhaps just using `scale()`. Mixed models can handle uneven and unbalanced time points so that's not a concern.